# Magento 2.2.6 - New categories not showing products

Tags: magento2, product, category, category-products, category-view

After created new category products not showing, it shows blank page with no error. But for other categories products shows. Any help should be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Have you tried do re-indexing using php bin/magento indexer:reindex command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this category some products prices are set to **`0.00`**, that's why it shows blank page. I ain't sure why Magento doesn't show any error regarding product price.

Thank you Amasty and Raj for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Magento usually shows message, that there are no products in your category. But you have only blank page. In most cases this is error. Try to switch to developer mode and in file `app/bootstrap.php` re-comment this code `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Now you should see error on your category page instead of blank. Also you can check error log files.